# shiny App : plot data based on sent variables from UI to server, one of the variable is date

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to change the shinyApp [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/016-knitr-pdf), so I have added two inputs to choose from when you want to graph the data. One column of my data is a date. I wasn't able to graph the data. I tried to factor the date field, but it might be the problem with the ShinyApp variables types because I tried to graph the data on a seperate example and it worked. I noticed the original example is using paste to format the `input$x` that is sent by the UI to the server, using function `regFormula ()`. I tried to change the structure, and even get rid of it. Still having error. Also, I tried to use **zoo** package which works again on a seperate example not inside the app.

here is the dataframe-using dput:

```
 structure(list(Dead = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), Case = c(120L, 70L, 50L, 40L, 39L, 20L, 18L, 13L, 9L, 2L), Recovered = c(30L, 
    0L, 18L, 13L, 19L, 10L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 1L), Critical = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L), Date = c("18/03/2020", "17/03/2020", 
    "16/03/2020", "15/03/2020", "14/03/2020", "13/03/2020", "12/03/2020", 
    "11/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "09/03/2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    10L))
```

if you check the date from above data using `str(df)`, date field will be chr type. Even I tried before loading the data to use `as.factor(df$Date)` to change it, no hope.

### ui.R:

```
fluidPage(
title = 'Download a PDF report',
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    helpText(),
    selectInput('x', 'Choose X-axis data',
              choices = names(dataMOH)),
    selectInput('y', 'Choose Y-axis data',
              choices = names(dataMOH)),
    radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport') ),
  mainPanel(
  plotOutput('regPlot')
   )
  )
 )
```

### server.R:

```
 function(input, output) {
      regFormula <- reactive({
      # as.formula(paste(input$x,'~ Date'))
        as.formula(paste(input$x,input$y))
      })

      output$regPlot <- renderPlot({
        par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1)) # margin lines
     #  plot(regFormula(), data = df, pch = 19) #df : dataframe name 
     #  plot(zoo(df$Case,as.Date(df$Date,"%d/%m/%y")))
        plot(zoo(df$(input$y),as.Date(df$(input$x),"%d/%m/%y")))

      })

     output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
       filename = function() {
       paste('my-Report', sep = '.', switch(
         input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
       ))
      },

     content = function(file) {
       src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
       # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
       # permission to the current working directory
        owd <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(owd))
       file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
       library(rmarkdown)
    out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
      input$format,
      PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()))
   file.rename(out, file)
  }
 )
}
```

what I'm missing here ?

Comment: A few issues that stand out - You need to use brackets to access the data by doing this `df[input$y]`. However, this returns a `data.frame`. To get the values you need to index the 1st (and only) column `df[input$y][,1]`.  Similarly `as.Date(df$(input$x),"%d/%m/%y")`should be `as.Date(df[input$x], format = "%d/%m/%Y")`.  Note the `%Y` instead of `%y`. Capitalizing the Y is for 4-digit year format, which you have. Lowercase y is for 2-digit year format.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues. I applied your comments and I got : ' Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date” '

Comment: Did you try setting the x input value to 'Date' in the app?

Comment: yes, but after I run the application from the drop down list. I don't know how to change the default loading x and y. It picks up the first values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to test out - thought this might be helpful to visualize.

A line was added to change the `Date` format with `as.Date` - this could be moved to a `reactive` expression if conversion is needed after loading a file.

I have two examples to show plots - one with `regFormula` using `reformulate` to create a function, and the second uses an optional `reactive` expression in case you want to select specific variables or do other manipulation.

It sounds like you might want to try setting `Date` as a default. This can be done by using `selected` in your `selectInput`.

Hope this helps.

```
library(shiny)

dataMOH$Date = as.Date(dataMOH$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      selectInput("x", "Choose X-axis data", choices = names(dataMOH), selected = "Date"),
      selectInput("y", "Choose Y-axis data", choices = names(dataMOH)),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
       tabPanel("Plot 1", plotOutput("regPlot1")),
       tabPanel("Plot 2", plotOutput("regPlot2"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  regFormula <- reactive({
   reformulate(termlabels = input$x, response = input$y)
  })

  myData <- reactive({
    dataMOH[, c(input$x, input$y)]
  })

  output$regPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1)) # margin lines
    plot(myData())
  })

  output$regPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, .1, .1)) # margin lines
    plot(regFormula(), data = dataMOH)
  })

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-Report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For a `plotly` plot you will need:

```
library(plotly)
```

Instead of `plotOutput` you will need:

```
plotlyOutput("regPlot1")
```

For one of the plots, you can include `renderPlotly`:

```
output$regPlot1 <- renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(ggplot(data = myData(), aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
             geom_point(size = 1, color = "blue"))
})
```

Comment: I'm getting error: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: We can discuss in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209896/room-for-ben-and-simpleneasy